# Chrome.exe : command not found

Tags: google-chrome, command-line-interface, git-bash

I try to automate vscode tasks like in  [video shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8UNHVO9qns).

I am using windows 11 and Git Bash and try to launch chrome via CLI.

Whenever i  run

```
chrome.exe http://localhost:8000
```

it returns "bash: chrome.exe: command not found" although the folder i am in contains chrome.exe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using

```
start chrome http://localhost:8000/
```